# What is the correct verb form for a list of tasks/responsibilities in CV?

Tags: grammar, conjugation

In my CV I have short lists of responsibilities/tasks that I was assigned in my past jobs. Should I use the -ing form of a verb in such lists or rather the infinitive?
For example:

> Accountant at XYZ
>
> Tasks:
>
> - Prepare project meetings
> - Calculate big meaningful numbers

or

> Accountant at XYZ
>
> Tasks:
>
> - Preparing project meetings
> - Calculating big meaningful numbers

Comment: I'd lean toward "preparation for..." and "calculation of..."

Comment: @KillingTime Good idea. I think, I’ll go with this. If you make it an answer, I’ll accept it.

Comment: The standard is to use the past tense, even for activities we are doing now.

Comment: @YosefBaskin like “prepared project meetings”? Isn’t that weird in listings without full sentences?

Comment: Prepared A, Managed B, Saved 11%. It's all standard resume style.

Comment: Both are OK as long as you maintain parallelism.

Answer (score 1):

**Action verbs** are the go-to.  [MIT](https://capd.mit.edu/sites/default/files/jobs/files/resume-action-verbs.pdf) gives a list of action verbs for CV writing that are all past tense.  The rule of thumb is on consistent verb tense, and since your work history is mostly in the past, use the past tense.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly it depends on how you phrase the preceding text.

My tasks were to:

- Prepare...
- Calculate...

I was tasked with:

- Preparing ...
- Calculating ...

Answer (score 0):

Everyone wants to make his/her resume catchy and unique, which is natural. Here, both styles should be fine, provided, minimum parallelism is maintained. E.g.,

Responsibilities include/ included,

- Preparing minutes
- Calculating sales figures

OR

- Preparation of minutes
- Calculation of sales figures

OR

Part of a multi-tasking team, I usually had to

- Prepare minutes
- Calculate sales figures

https://www.monster.com/career-advice/article/military-resume-sample: Relevant part of this link is here:

Under 'experience' details:

•   Performed regular foot patrols, escorted residents ...

•   Provided informational assistance and directional guidance to ...

•   Responded swiftly and reacted calmly to reported incidents ...